# Print items from list in specific order, python

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I am trying to print items from two list (l, val) in a specific order. My code goes here..

I tried to loop through the portion after (.) by taking it to a variable, but its getting updated during execution.

While printing the item with a.b1/ (.) in between, need to slpit it at (.) as i did and the portion after (.) should be printed with more spaces, till the first part of itwm remains the same, for example, in case of items like a.b1/, a.b2/, a.b3/,  first 'a' should be printed and with equal distance from left b1,b2,b3 should be printed and last 'a' should be printed with same distance first 'a' kept from left.

My code goes here.

```
l = ['a1','b2','c3','d4','e5','a.b1/','a.b2/','a.b3/','e5','f6','g7','q.a1/','q.a2/','q.a3/','h','i','j']
val = ['None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None']
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        if l[i][-1:] == '/':
            l_p = l[i].split('.')[0]
            l_c = (l[i].split('.')[1]).strip('/')
            print('       '+'%s'%l_p+' \n')
            print('         '+l_c+' '+'%s'%val[i]+' '+l_c+' '+'\n')
            print('        '+'%s'%l_p+' \n')
        else:
            print('       '+l[i]+' '+'%s'%val[i]+' '+l[i]+' '+'\n')
```

my out put is

```
   a1 None a1 
   b2 None b2 
   c3 None c3 
   d4 None d4 
   e5 None e5 
   a 
     b1 None b1 
    a 
   a 
     b2 None b2 
    a 
   a 
     b3 None b3 
    a 
   e5 None e5 
   f6 None f6 
   g7 None g7 
   q 
     a1 None a1 
    q 
   q 
     a2 None a2 
    q 
   q 
     a3 None a3 
    q 
   h None h 
   i None i 
   j None j
```

My expected output is :

```
  a1 None a1
  b2 None b2
  c3 None c3
  d4 None d4
  e5 None e5
  a
    b1 None b1
    b2 None b2
    b3 None b3
  a
  e5 None e5
  f6 None f6
  g7 None g7
  q
    a1 None a1
    a2 None a2
    a3 None a3
  q
  h None h
  i None i
  j None j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of the category, you are in, i.e. the part before the dot. It would have been easier, if you didn't want to print out the category at the end of each block again, but here we go:

```
prev_cat = ""
for i, item in enumerate(l):     #iterate over the list
    if item.endswith("/"):       #identify category and category element, set tabulator
        curr_cat, printitem = item[:-1].split(".")
        tabulator = "    "    
    else:
        curr_cat, printitem, tabulator = "", item, ""

    #identify category, changes in category, print categories
    if curr_cat and (curr_cat != prev_cat):    
        if prev_cat:
            print(prev_cat)
        print(curr_cat)
    elif not curr_cat and prev_cat:
        print(prev_cat)

    prev_cat = curr_cat
    #print category items from both lists
    print(tabulator + " ".join([printitem, val[i], printitem]))  

if curr_cat:    #close the last category, if necessary
    print(curr_cat)
```

It doesn't check, if `val` has enough elements to print or if `l` contains strings or if each string in `l` that ends with `/` actually contains exactly two parts separated by one dot. This is treated as a given as specified by your question.